# Unable to disable windows key when key is pressed?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I wrote a simple jQuery in my JSP page so when a user presses the windows key (left windows key), it should not respond to anything. In other words,it's disabled.

This is how I implemented it:

```
 $('html').bind('keypress', function(e)
            {
                if(e.keyCode == 91)
                {
                    alert("This is disabled");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

However,it doesn't do anything at all neither does it throw the alert message out and I couldn't figure what did I do wrong.

Comment: The browser can trigger events when keyboard keys are pressed, however it is not able to prevent the default Operating System behaviours of keys. That is by intent to stop people blocking keyboard input for users. If you want to do this, then you will need to use a different language. I myself, used to do such things like this in a language called AutoIT. You can also embed an Internet Explorer frame into an AutoIT GUI and then with that Web Browser-like program, you can take control of an input and stop it's default Operating System behaviour. Good Luck!

Comment: @MichaelThompson It's seem cumbersome to do it outside of the code though but thanks for the input!